# Why did my well behaved cat suddenly start biting and meowing?

Tags: cats, behavior

I'm not even sure how to begin with this. I have a very well behaved and sweet cat who does not usually show aggression. Today, he walked over to me as if he wanted to cuddle, but then proceeded to bite and meow as I have never heard before. Every time his jaw moved, he would meow as if distressed. I thought this may have been a dental problem or something, but he was at the vet just a few weeks ago and they saw no problems. I allowed him to bite without jerking back, because that usually makes him stop and become cuddly. Instead of stopping, he started to pull very hard, like a dog tugging on a bone. He kept backing up, like he was trying to lead me somewhere, but stopped and slowly walked off as soon as I began to follow him.

I have no idea what this whole episode was about and I hope I described it well enough. Does anybody have any idea what could be happening?

Comment: How old is this cat? Is he an outgoing or indoors cat? You don't have other pets, right?

Comment: Have there been any other behavior changes? Is your cat eating normally? Also, check for injuries - whether he's favoring a limb, moving awkwardly, or shows distress when you touch a certain part of his body (even with short haired cats the fur can hide injuries)

Comment: Is he neutered?

Comment: I hope your cat is vaccinated for rabies and the like.  I'd really recommend a vet visit with a description of all the symptoms

Comment: If not vaccinated against rabies, the cat, and possibly the human, could be dead by now.

Answer (score 6):

Sudden unexplained  behavior change always calls for a vet visit.

Answer (score 3):

Your cat might be going through cat puberty, it makes them become aggressive and start wanting to go outside more. They will also start marking their territory by peeing everywhere.

Also, if your cat is running around your house like crazy and is grooming more than usual, he might have fleas.

In conclusion, check with your vet if you're not sure!

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with keshlam, watch his diet and water intake, try to determine whether he has any health issues or is suffering from pain, just in case.

But to be honest, I think maybe he was just having one of those lets be naughty days, which I find hilarious. Give it a few days and watch closely.

Please note that if it's a young male, he might be getting ready for breeding, in any case, unless you want to breed, make sure to get them neutered.

But for males, it will especially make them much more mellow and content.

Answer (score 0):

Could be cat puberty, but also could be rabies. I agree with keshlam on this one, go and see a vet. If you don't have the time, try a video vet consultation with Pawsquad or vetondemand depending on where you're based.